# List View in QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I need to implement a list / listView to create a notification menu but I am wondering how to do it so that my object will stay generic and each of row will have adjustable height and weight.
I am adding picture below so you can envision easier what I am talking about.

Main issue is, that the rows can be / even must have different size, it is up to state if I press go_back (arrow on the left), then we should get different info, so the rows will change height.

[image]

Comment: Can you add List View and it's delegate code, please

Comment: It's possible a `DelegateModel` could help you. It allows you to define `groups` . You can change how the delegate is drawn based on what group it is in.